# Необходимо ли менять запятую на тире? Можно ли обойтись вообще без знака? (→)

Tags: пунктуация

> Я попросила себе полный чайник чаю, свежего, ещё горячего бурека –
>   пирожка с мясом из слоёного теста, домашнего каймака – чуть
>   солоноватых, копчёных сливок, и принялась гадать: кто же первым из
>   постояльцев окажется мне соседом.

Попросила того-сего и принялась гадать.

А как быть с тем, что вовнутрях?

Неуж второе тире?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос... А зачем после "сливок" запятая? Эх, слюньки текут!

Comment: Вот про нея и вопрос. А как оформить *– чуть солоноватых, копчёных сливок, и принялась гадать*? Не иначе как вторым тире прикрывать...

Comment: Третьим тогда уж)

Comment: Правильно не видите. Верной дорогой идёте, товарищ!

Comment: @Бот Ботович, что за такой учебник у вас?

Comment: Не настолько новый, однако ещё действующий. Быстрова 8 класс, если рассматривать сугубо данный вопрос, а так пользуюсь всем курсом.

Comment: ***Я попросила себе полный чайник чаю, свежего, ещё горячего бурека (пирожок с мясом из слоёного теста), домашнего каймака (чуть солоноватые копчёные сливки) и принялась гадать: кто же первым из постояльцев окажется мне соседом?***

Comment: @БотБотович, рассматривать пунктуацию на этом форуме по учебнику 8 класса - это,простите, несерьезно. Да и вообще, вопрос не школьного уровня.

Comment: Да что Вы говорите. Тут в последнее время в ответах одни догадки выкладывают, а Вы учебники, одобренные министерстом, критикуете...

Comment: Я не критикую, тем более я в лицо не видел этот учебник.

Comment: @БотБотович используйте для ответов ответы, а не комментарии.

Comment: Где Вы тут увидели ответ? Согласно правилам форума, "ответы должны быть подробными", однако мой комментарий в эту категорию не попадает. И ответ под постом Галины я писать не собираюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, приложения у Вас выделены с помощью одиночного тире по правилу
справочника РАН Лопатина (у Розенталя то же самое):

> § 65. Приложения отделяются одиночным тире (второе тире поглощается
>   другим знаком или опускается):
>
> 5) если приложение имеет более конкретное значение в сравнении со
>   значением определяемого слова: Источник силы от матери — родной
>   земли представляется для всех источником важным и целебным (второе тире
>   опущено).

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

**Не вижу никаких условий для постановки запятой** после последнего приложения, если только здесь нет авторского присоединения - паузы. Авторского - потому что при нормальном прочтении паузы нет, для присоединения характерно последующее неожиданное действие, а здесь всё логично, ровно: попросила себе чаю,  бурека , каймака  и принялась гадать...

Возможны варианты. Последнее предложение всё-таки вопросительное, если с двоеточием в БСП, поэтому в конце вопросительный знак.

*Я попросила себе полный чайник чаю, свежего, ещё горячего бурека – пирожка с мясом из слоёного теста, домашнего каймака – чуть солоноватых, копчёных сливок и принялась гадать: кто же первым из постояльцев окажется мне соседом?*

Возможно и предложение с прямой речью, если передаётся внутренняя речь героини без изменения:

*Я попросила себе полный чайник чаю, свежего, ещё горячего бурека – пирожка с мясом из слоёного теста, домашнего каймака – чуть солоноватых, копчёных сливок и принялась гадать: "Кто же первым из постояльцев окажется мне соседом?"*.

Если же знака вопроса нет, то оформить следует как СПП, с  запятой вместо двоеточия:

*Я попросила себе полный чайник чаю, свежего, ещё горячего бурека – пирожка с мясом из слоёного теста, домашнего каймака – чуть солоноватых, копчёных сливок и принялась гадать, кто же первым из постояльцев окажется мне соседом.*

А вот после приложений перед И, по-моему, **никакого знака нет**.

Comment: Можно, конечно, и так, только чтение текста получается монотонным и невыразительным. С другой стороны, это стандартный вариант (по правилам), ничего из авторской пунктуации, а это тоже своего рода преимущество. Запятой была, вероятно, обозначена очень желательная здесь пауза (ведь союз И всегда можно посчитать присоединительным).

Answer (score 2):

А можно немного  пофантазировать? Наверное, нельзя много исправлять и вариант не подойдет,  но мне было бы удобно читать так:

*Я попросила себе полный  чайник чаю; свежего, ещё горячего бурека – пирожка с мясом из слоёного теста; домашнего каймака – чуть солоноватых, копчёных сливок, – и (я) принялась гадать, кто же первым из постояльцев окажется мне соседом.*

Точку с запятой пришлось применить, так как много своих знаков в каждой порции. Тире и запятая как единый знак на границе (блоков?).  Двоеточие лучше заменить запятой, чтобы не останавливаться в конце.

Я добавлю еще пояснение об обособлении приложений одним тире.

Из правил Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Пишется одно тире:

4) для внесения ясности, если приложение относится к одному из однородных членов предложения:

В оранжерее разводились магнолии, камелии — цветы Японии, орхидеи и цикламены; За столом сидели хозяйка дома, её сестра — подруга моей жены, двое незнакомых мне лиц, моя жена и я; Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях — жертвах жизни и о людях — владыках её (М. Г.).

Comment: Простите, Май, но публиковать ответ под постом Галины равносильно разговору со стеной. Поставлю Вам плюсик хоть.

Comment: Спасибо за "плюсик хоть".

Comment: Я ещё вдумаюсь на трезвую голову (не спамши мы), но у нас явно не *обособление приложений одним тире*, мне мешает знак после "сливок! Думу буду думати.

Comment: Здесь явно однородные дополнения, а у каждого дополнения свое приложение. Это соответствует правилу обособления одним тире. А дальше нестандартный вариант - союз "и" перед однородным сказуемым. Да еще хорошо бы паузу сделать, чтобы от перечисления блюд перейти к следующей теме. Поэтому однородное  сказуемое лучше переделать в сложное предложение, а паузу обозначить дополнительным тире. Или это будет запятая и тире как единый знак для обозначения двух блоков. Мне кажется, что здесь нужно  выбрать удобное прочтение текста, а потом подобрать правила к готовому решению. Удачного Вам выбора!

Comment: Автор проснулись и ждут-с. Шлю-с.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего запятая нужна. Можно признать, что союз и здесь носит присоединительный характер. Поскольку в вашем примере нет одновременности действий. Она попросила... и (сразу) принялась гадать.

Если союз и имеет присоединительное значение (с помощью этого союза может присоединяться также неоднородный член предложения), то перед ним ставится запятая:

**[Лизавета Ивановна] разливала чай, и получала выговоры за лишний расход сахара; она вслух читала романы, и виновата была во всех ошибках автора; она сопровождала графиню в её прогулках, и отвечала за погоду и за мостовую (П.);**

Розенталь. Д.Э.

Comment: Сержик, доброе утро! У меня такая проблема: ***Я попросила каймака – чуть солоноватых копчёных сливок, и принялась гадать***, т. е. разъяснение открылось тире, а закрылось запятой, что неможно.

Comment: – Galina Avanesova, тире открывает приложение, которая находится в конце предложения. А запятая закрывает приложение. Если заменить запятую на тире, получится вставная конструкция. А здесь это невозможно.

Comment: Низзя! Что открылось тире, им и должно закрыться. Уточняющее - либо в двух запятых, либо в двух тире, либо в скобках. Четверциум нон датур! )))

Comment: С помощью тире открывается и закрывается вставная конструкция. А у нас не тот случай.

Comment: У нас объяснение, что такое каймак.

Comment: Уточняюшие приложения выделяются с помощью тире с двух сторон в середине предложения.

Comment: Ааа, что делать?! Я попросила чаю, бурека, каймак и принялась гадать. Автор не любит скобок... ***Я попросила себе полный чайник чаю, свежего, ещё горячего бурека (пирожок с мясом из слоёного теста), домашнего каймака (чуть солоноватые копчёные сливки) и принялась гадать: кто же первым из постояльцев окажется мне соседом?***

Comment: Извините, что я вмешиваюсь (эпизод как из "Мастера и Маргариты")....но предмет вашей  беседы настолько интересен...  Мне кажется, что вы обсуждаете постановку одного или двух тире при обособлении приложений. Я добавила в свой ответ правило на ту тему, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova, а чем плох ваш вариант?

Comment: @May, вы как раз и приводите то правило.

Comment: Сержик, мне почему-то очень понравился мой вариант - я им горжусь: такой красивый выход из сложной ситуации, но... автор просил меня не плодить скобки. Вот отправлю ему всё здешнее хозяйство и - пусть думает!

Comment: Да, скобками выделять приложение не хорошо. Отправляйте. Хотя, подождем, может, будут другие версии.