# Если определений четыре, можно их чохом дать на запятых?

Tags: пунктуация

> Вот целая улица **милых сердцу, трогательных, трёхэтажных, мёртвых**
>   особнячков, что с упрёком выглядывают из-под яркого наряда граффити.

Так у автора; что-то же он имел в виду?

Или непременно:

> Вот целая улица **милых сердцу, трогательных трёхэтажных мёртвых**
>   особнячков, что с упрёком выглядывают из-под яркого наряда граффити.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, что имел в виду автор, только **трогательных трёхэтажных мёртвых** -
 никак не однородные определения. На художественный приём не похоже. Трёхэтажные трогательными как-то не назовёшь, трогательные маленькие деревенские домики, а чем трогает **мёртвый особнячок**? Над мёртвым хочется плакать, а не умиляться.

Comment: А это вот как раз то, что я попросила автора вставить в посвящение (окончательной редакции не видела): *Мой «питерский акцент» остался нетронутым...* Там у них (питерцев) все оттенки смыслов иные. И "трёхэтажный мёртвый" может растрогать, после небоскрёбов-то. Вот сейчас читаю: "... вот семья, с ребёнком в коляске, покупает на ужин скупые хот-доги", - я никогда и не придумала бы "скупые"... А грамота говорит: 3. Бедный чем-л., скудный.

Comment: "Скупые хот-доги" мне нравится, может, и трёхэтажные  по сравнению с небоскрёбами умилительны, а вот мёртвые особнячки вряд ли вызывают умиление и любовь, чувство здесь другое - печаль, а не растроганность.  Мне кажется, нельзя все определения считать однородными, лучше всё-таки убрать запятые.

Comment: Придите, пожалуйста: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452642/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%E2%86%92 , а то там боты меня интерпретируют. А ответ определённо не по душе: что за громоздёж знаков!

Comment: @Людмила, мне кажется, автору просто  хотелось выделить какие-то отличительные признаки особняков, только вот он в смысл не вник. И получилось то, что получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Ассоциативно [трехэтажный особнячок + небоскреб?]: "развеселенький" коробок спичек (с цветочной или абстрактной этикеткой) рядом с унылой коробищей из-под телевизора действительно смотрится мило и трогательно.

А вот прилагательное *мёртвые* выглядит грубовато, я бы, возможно, заменила его на *безжизненные* (пустынные, безлюдные, необитаемые, неживые, погибающие/погибшие) и поставила **но**. Тогда, как мне кажется, однородный ряд вырисовывается.

*Вот целая улица милых сердцу, трогательных, трёхэтажных, но безжизненных особнячков, что с упрёком выглядывают из-под яркого наряда граффити.*